# Lucene .NET IndexWriter lock

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

My question related to the next code snippet:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Lucene.Net.Store.Directory d = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(/*my index path*/));
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(d, new WhitespaceAnalyzer());

    //Exiting without closing the indexd writer...
}
```

In this test, I opened an IndexWriter without closing it - so even after the test exits, the write.lock file still exists in the index directory, so I expected that the next time I open an instance of IndexWriter to that index, a `LockObatinFailedException` will be thrown.
Can someone please explain to me why am I wrong? I mean, does the meaning of the write.lock file is to protect creation of two IndexWriters in the same process only? that doesnt seems the right answer to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug with that IndexWriter constructor, if you change your code to:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter("Path to index here", new WhitespaceAnalyzer());
```

You will get the Exception.

The lock file is used to prevent 2 IndexWriter opened on the same index, whether they are in the same process or not. You are right to expect an Exception there.

Comment: It seems that you are right! All constructors that takes Directory instead of string wont throw exception... I wonder if this issue was fixed in later version. Anyway, thanks a lot :)